# pgpool 4.2.1 and postgres 11 streaming replication problem

Tags: postgresql, replication, pgpool

I've setup a 2+2 pgpool and postgresql cluster.
two pgpool nodes in active/standby configuration  and a streaming replication between databases
All seemed work fine until after some failover and online recovery tests took place.
Suddenly I no longer able to  see the "streaming" status from either "show pool_nodes" or "pcp_node_info commands. all users have the pg_monitor role granted.
I'm unable to understand why I was able to see the "streaming" ( and async) repliction status , but not any more .

Could someone help me to understand why?

postgres=# show pool_nodes;

```
postgres=# show pool_nodes;
 node_id | hostname | port | status | lb_weight |  role   | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay | replication_state | replication_sync_state | last_status_change  
---------+----------+------+--------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------+---------------------
 0       | xxxxxxx  | 5432 | up     | 0.500000  | primary | 0          | false             | 0                 |                   |                        | 2021-03-16 01:37:19
 1       | yyyyyy  | 5432 | up     | 0.500000  | standby | 0          | true              | 0                 |                   |                        | 2021-03-16 01:37:19
(2 rows)
```

or from the pcp_node_info  command

```
[postgres@xxxxxxx ~]$ pcp_node_info --verbose -h localhost 0
Password: 
Hostname               : xxxxxxx
Port                   : 5432
Status                 : 3
Weight                 : 0.500000
Status Name            : down
Role                   : standby
Replication Delay      : 0
Replication State      :  <<<=== it is empty
Replication Sync State :  <<<=== it is empty
Last Status Change     : 2021-03-16 00:02:59
[postgres@yyyyyyyy ~]$ pcp_node_info --verbose -h localhost 1
Password: 
Hostname               : yyyyyyyy
Port                   : 5432
Status                 : 1
Weight                 : 0.500000
Status Name            : waiting
Role                   : primary
Replication Delay      : 0
Replication State      :          
Replication Sync State :
```